# Google App Engine Objectify 5.1.21 - Many-to-many relationship queries

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I'm new on Objectify coding and I need your help to solve a problem with Many-to-many relationship query.

I have 2 entities named User and Installation:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id private String login;
    private String password;
    @Index private String name;
    @Index private String firstName;
    @Index private byte right;
}

@Entity
public class Installation {
    @Id private long id;
    @Index private long clientId;
    @Index private String name;
    private String address1;
    private String address2;
    @Index private String postCode;
    private String city;
    @Index private String countryCode;
    @Index private int status;
}
```

A user can access to several installation and an installation can have several users : many-to-many relationship. I want to map these entities but I don't want to load systematically installations when I load users. So, I created an entity for mapping Users and Installations :

```
@Entity
public class InstallUser {
    @Id private Long id;
    @Index Key<User> userKey;
    @Index Key<Installation> instalKey;

    public void setLink(User user, Installation instal){
        //initialize
        this.userKey = Key.create(User.class, user.getLogin());
        this.instalKey = Key.create(Installation.class, instal.getId());
    }
}
```

Could you help me for writing the queries to :

1. load all installations of a user identified by his login (@id) ;
2. load all users who have access to an installation identified by its id (@id) ;
3. load all installations of a user identified by his login (@id) and filtered by his right (right=2 for example).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the datastore doesn't do joins for you, you can still do joins - you're the query planner. So do what an RDBMS would do. For example, to perform #1 ("load all installations of a user identified by his login") you would:

1. Make a `Key<User>` for that user
2. Find all `InstallUser`s associated with that user
3. Use all the relevant `Key<Installation>`s to batch load the installatons.

You can be slightly more clever by using `Ref<?>`s instead of `Key<?>`s in the `InstallUser` and using the `@Load` annotation to automatically fetch the `Installation`.

There are quite a few other ways of structuring this data as well. Depending on the arity of the relationships, you might use a list property in either `User` or `Installation` instead of a separate relationship entity. But you're on the right path.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
If I understand correctly, for queries #1 and #2 I need to run 2 queries into Objectify to load a list: load Keys<?> and then load the list from the Keys<?>. Is it possible to write only 1 query ? 
Is there any solution for query #3 ?
You said the Ref<?> would be more smart. Could you developed ?

Comment: You can't do it as a single query because the datastore does not do joins for you. You have to mimic the behavior of a database query planner.

For #3 you might find it easiest to denormalize the data - that is, pull some of the data in Installation (`right`) into the `InstallUser` so that you can filter by it.

The datastore involves some tradeoffs. You don't get SQL or joins or aggregations, but you get a zero-maintenance, infinitely scalable database. It varies app-to-app whether this tradeoff is worthwhile.

Comment: @stickfigure Doesn't the `@Load` annotation also work for `Key<T>` fields?

Comment: No, not currently. It's not a bad idea though. I'm in the middle of a big rewrite for v6, but maybe this is a good idea for 6.1.